# Allowing expess to pass routes to react-router

Tags: express, reactjs, react-router

I have an express webpack react / react router app (^2.0.0-rc5) I am working on. In express, I am using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));` to map my react app to a url.

when I go to `http://localhost:3001/` in my app, it navigates fine. then when I click on a button `Link` 'ing to `http://localhost:3001/diff-place` , it navigates to the new page.

however, when I go straight to `http://localhost:3001/diff-place` , express intercepts the request and issues a 404.

I'm not sure how to work around this, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of your express routes, make sure you have a catch all route defined that will load the client for any page request, and make sure to replace index.html in the example with whatever your html entry point is. At that point react-router will kick in.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + 'dist/index.html'));
});
```